# XCode automatically generated comments?

Tags: xcode, comments

Every time when I create a new file in XCode, it makes some comment at the top of the file.
Recently it has changed somehow - I dont know why and how to reset this.

Its now like this:

```
//
//  [Filename.cpp]
//  [Projectname]
//
//  Created by [Name] on [Date]
//  Copyright 2011 [Company]. All rights reserved.
//
```

But was first like this:

```
/*
 *  [Filename.cpp]
 *  [Projectname]
 *
 *  Created by [Name] on [Date]
 *  Copyright 2011 [Company]. All rights reserved.
 *
 */
```

So is there some setting, where I can reset this style of auto generated comments? Where I can I change this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On a default installation, the directory "/Developer/Library/XCode/File Templates" has all the new file templates.

Comment: in 4.5: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/XCode/Templates

Answer (score 2):

It's in the template files; here's a post about [providing custom templates](http://www.macresearch.org/custom_xcode_templates) (the paths might have changed, but the technique still works).