# How to get the "Created by <name> on <date>" text

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

So the question is actually simple, but I have no idea how to approach this issue. I know this code is generated by template based on this question:

[XCode automatically generated comments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4803600/xcode-automatically-generated-comments)

I want to use the **`<name>`** that xcode provides on each mac machine which is unique for it's user, for some types of logs.

**EDIT:**

This is how the swift template file looks before it's used by Xcode to create my work file:

```
//
//  ___FILENAME___
//  ___PROJECTNAME___
//
//  Created by ___FULLUSERNAME___ on ___DATE___.
//___COPYRIGHT___
//
```

Surely, there is no point in parsing it.

**The question is:** Does anyone knows how I can get this name using swift in my application?

I searched for an answer here/Google but so far no luck.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do and when? Do you want info about the original creator of a source code file, or whoever last changed it, or the user running the app, etc? Do you want it in your running app as shipped in the App Store, while debugging in the simulator, or as part of your build process? There are answers here for some of those cases, but are those cases what you need?

Comment: I'm trying to display the current developer's name in the log of xcode. so for each developer a different name will appear in his computer.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how to read the header. But you can do it otherwise.

First if you need the creation-date of a file, you can use the `NSFileManager`:

```
var path = "path/to/your/file/"
var fileAttribs:NSDictionary = NSFileManager.defaultManager().attributesOfFileSystemForPath(path, error: nil)!

var creationDate = fileAttribs.objectForKey(NSFileCreationDate)
```

Also if you need the full username, you can use the function `NSFullUserName()` or `NSUserName()`. It should return the same string as `__FULLUSERNAME__`

```
var fullUsername = NSFullUserName()
var username = NSUserName()
```

Sometimes in the iOS Simulator, this username is empty, but in a real app, it should work properly.

Comment: `NSUserName()` gives the user's login—you probably want `NSFullUserName()` for that field.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I've added it to my answer.

Comment: In iOS, all apps run as the user "mobile", whose full name is "Mobile User". This probably isn't the name you're looking for.

Comment: not NSUserName() or NSFullUserName() does not give me the data that I want.

Answer (score 0):

That text written at template instantiation time — that is, when you create a new Xcode project (or a new file in an existing project using the **File > New > File...** templates). You can't read the contents of the source file your code was compiled from. (Well, unless you ship that file along with your compiled binary, and read it in like any other text file.)

But that's just text substitution — it can be done anywhere in the file, not just in the comment headers. So you could create your own file or project templates, and in the template files, put those substitution macros in code instead of in comments:

```
let schmoeWhoCreatedThisFile = "___FULLUSERNAME___"
```

[Here's a tutorial](http://www.bobmccune.com/2012/03/04/creating-custom-xcode-4-file-templates/) found in a couple seconds of web searching that has the full details on creating templates and the substitution macros you can use in them.

Remember, substitution happens when you *create* a new file or project — if you're looking for who made the latest change to your source file or who built the app that shipped to your customers, you're barking up the wrong tree. Some of those sorts of things you can do [with source control](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Attributes); others are more a matter of (human-defined, human-executed) policy for you or or your organization.

Comment: You really went far with it, like I said I'm not looking to create another template or anything of that sort, the question simply was: "Does anyone knows how I can get this name using swift in my application?" Isnt there anyother way that will let me to get this parameter without creating a new template?

Comment: As noted in my answer, you can't read at runtime the source code file(s) your app was compiled from.